# Adding rows to a 100K+ dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, data-science

Im really new to Python and Data science.

I have a 100K+ CSV Dataset with 30 columns. The goal is to add some rows to the dataset if some condition are satisfied.

To make things easier, let's say i have only three column named "A", "B" and "C", type of A and B is integer. C is a String.

Let's not worry about B and C, as im gonna put all B column value to 0 and im gonna calculate C later on.

So here's a quick view to my "Imaginary" dataset:

```
   A
 _____
|  1  |
|  4  |
|  3  |
|  7  |
_______
```

I parsed my dataset in a Dataframe and i sorted it by value of "A".

So, now, it looks like this :

```
   A
 _____
|  1  |
|  3  |
|  4  |
|  7  |
_______
```

Now, i want to iterate over my DataFrame and check if im missing some number between two rows and add them to the dataframe, i.e: if A[i+1]-A[i]>1, i wanna add A[i]+1 between them.

```
   A
 _____
|  1  |
|  2  |
|  3  |
|  4  |
|  5  |
|  6  |
|  7  |
_______
```

So as far as i know i have these choices:

1. Append my new rows directly to a new Dataframe. I don't know why
   but i think that it's not a good idea. If im right, can you guys
   explain why ? If im wrong, can you guys explain why?
2. Append my new rows to a List, make a DataFrame from that List and "Join" my old DataFrame with my new.
3. Idk, any suggestion?

My main problem now, is that dealing with a large DataFrame is a pain in the ass, and my script takes ages to do the job. Can you guys lead me to "Right way" of dealing with such large amount of data ?

Btw, here's the code i made for choice n°2:

```
df=pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
df.sort_values(by="A")
L=[]
for i in range (0, len(df)-1):
    actual=df.at[i, 'A']
    next=df.at[(i+1), 'A']
    diff=actual-next-1
    for j in range(1, diff):
        L.append(actual+1)
        actual +=1
df=pd.DataFrame(data=L, columns=list(df))
df.to_csv("my_output.csv", sep=',')
```

Comment: What should happen with the other columns?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem im just gonna put them to zero for int columns and i have one categorical column that im gonna calculate later, good comment, im gonna specify this on my post, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `reindex`

Set `'A'` to the index and `reindex` will create a row for each value we specify, accomplished with `range`. Missing cells for all other columns are (float and object, respectively). There is no need to sort prior to the `reindex`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4, 3, 1, 7], 
                   'B': [10, 11, 12, 13], 
                   'C': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'],
                   'D': [True, False, True, True]})

idx = range(df.A.min(), df.A.max()+1)  # All 'A' values you want to represent
df.set_index('A').reindex(idx).reset_index()
#   A     B    C      D
#0  1  12.0   B3   True
#1  2   NaN  NaN    NaN
#2  3  11.0   B2  False
#3  4  10.0   B1   True
#4  5   NaN  NaN    NaN
#5  6   NaN  NaN    NaN
#6  7  13.0   B4   True
```

---

If `'A'` is duplicated, then we need an `outer` join to accomplish the same.

```
(df.set_index('A')
   .join(pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index(idx, name='A')), how='outer')
   .reset_index())
```

Comment: What if "A" was a Datetime, can we use the same thing ?

Comment: @lefragan Yes. And if it's a `datetime` dtype then you can set the index and use [`DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) assuming you want a regular frequency. Similarly you could use `pd.date_range` to create the list of times and reindex just like above.

Comment: what about filling the B columns with zeros and C with Empty Strings, is there a quick method to achieve this?

Comment: @lefragan If you want to keep the original data and just fill the missing values, you can add on a `.fillna({'B': 0, 'C': ''})`. If you instead want to overwrite all values regardless, then instead add on: `.assign(**{'B': 0, 'C': ''})`. If it's the latter, you almost might just want to reconstruct the DataFrame from the start if you just need no information from the other columns and just the range of A values. Something like `pd.DataFrame({'A': idx, 'B': 0, 'C': ''})`

Answer (score 0):

Let us recreate your DataFrame and index it by `A`:

```
rows = [1, 4, 3, 7]
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": rows, "B": [1] * len(rows), "C": ["string"] * len(rows)})
N = df.A.max()
df = df.set_index("A")
```

One option is to create a new DataFrame filled with all possible entries for `A` and with zeros in `B`:

```
complete_df = pd.DataFrame({"A": range(1, N + 1), "B": [0] * N})
complete_df = complete_df.set_index("A")
```

Now you can just update with the values in `df` and remove the indexing on `A`:

```
complete_df = df.combine_first(complete_df)
complete_df = complete_df.reset_index()
```

This way, you will preserve all columns, put zeros in the column `B` for all new rows, and have `NaN` in all other columns.